# Forbid the publication

Tags: 7, users

I created a new role for the user to write.
How do I forbid the publication to a redactor?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, I think you want the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module.  You probably also need the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module, and potentially the [Module Grants](http://drupal.org/project/module_grants) and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules.

I don't recall testing this particular workflow, though.  It is also worth noting that workflows can be a pain to set up, and adding workflow to an existing site can be problematic because existing nodes will not have a workflow yet (some scripts to fix this are available if you poke around).

This question is tagged for Drupal 7, which presents a problem with this solution.  Workflow and Module Grants don't have D7 versions yet.  There are discussions about ports in the issues, but nothing has been released yet.

Comment: Worflow doesn't have a Drupal 7 version.

Comment: I never noticed that.  Should I delete this answer?  Edit it?

Comment: I would rather edit it, and report that Workflow would be the perfect candidate, if it had a Drupal 7 version. There is already an issue report about a Drupal 7 version, and it will be surely created; the problem is that is not clear when it will created. Deleting the answer seems too excessive, as it is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [publish content module](http://drupal.org/project/publishcontent). It's available for d6 and d7.

Answer (score 0):

### I asked a related question.  And here's the answer someone gave me

Just unchecked publish checkbox on content type setting page and hide this field with CSS if user has writer role or remove it programmatically on the same condition with hook_form_alter

Use the revisioning module to prevent writer's from publishing "revisions of existing content".